# Does $\lim_{n \to \infty}\inf_{x\in X} f_n (x) = \inf_{x\in X} f (x)$ hold where $f_n$ is bounded Lipschitz continuous such that $f_n \uparrow f$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, metric-spaces, supremum-and-infimum, lipschitz-functions

Let $X$ be a Polish space, $f_n: X \to \mathbb R$ bounded Lipschitz continuous, and $f: X \to \mathbb R \cup \{+\infty\}$  such that  $f_n \uparrow f$ pointwise. Then
$$
A :=\lim_{n \to \infty}\inf_{x\in X} f_n (x) \le B:= \inf_{x\in X} f (x).
$$

Does the reverse inequality $A \ge B$ hold? Thank you so much for your elaboration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A counterexample is the sequence of functions $f_n:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ given by
$$f_n(x)=\frac{1}{\pi}\arctan(n-x)+\frac{1}{2},$$
which increases pointwise to $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, $f(x)=1$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. However, we have
$$\inf_{x\in\mathbb{R}}f_n(x)=0$$
for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, but
$$\inf_{x\in\mathbb{R}}f(x)=1.$$